# uninitialized constant DeviseMailersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using the devise gem and previously created a controller `DeviseMailersController`, but have since deleted it with `rails d controller DeviseMailers`. When I try to send a reset password email I get an error with the following:

```
  NameError in Devise::PasswordsController#create
  uninitialized constant DeviseMailersController

  names.inject(Object) do |constant, name|
    if constant == Object
      constant.const_get(name)
    else
      candidate = constant.const_get(name)
      next candidate if constant.const_defined?(name, false)
```

I have placed the smtp settings inside the application.rb file.

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AssessmentWebApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
      port:                 587,
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name:            ENV["google_username"],
      password:             ENV["google_password"],
      authentication:       'plain'
    }
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```